# Does ehcache 3.8.1 still use ehcache.xml for configuration?

Tags: ehcache, ehcache-3

Does ehcache 3.8.1 no longer automatically pick up the configuration settings in an ehcache.xml file at the source root directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's looks so, now it needs to be done using a XML file by [configuringe a CacheManager](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.8/getting-started.html#configuring-with-xml) at creation time, according to [this schema definition](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.8/xsds.html#core).

XML programmatic parsing

If you are obtaining your CacheManager through the JSR-107 API, what follows is done automatically when invoking 
`javax.cache.spi.CachingProvider.getCacheManager(java.net.URI, java.lang.ClassLoader)`

```
final URL myUrl = getClass().getResource("/configs/docs/getting-started.xml"); 
XmlConfiguration xmlConfig = new XmlConfiguration(myUrl); 
CacheManager myCacheManager = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManager(xmlConfig); 
myCacheManager.init();
```

1. Obtain a URL to your XML file’s location
2. Instantiate an XmlConfiguration passing the XML file’s URL to it
3. Using the static

```
org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManager(org.ehcache.config.Configuration)
```

allows you to create your CacheManager instance using the Configuration from the XmlConfiguration

4. Initialize the cacheManager before it is used.

Reference - http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.8/xml.html